# PrintDocument does not print an image on a DL envelope in normal resolution, it must be 220x110mm, but I get a 205x100mm image

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

PrintDocument does not print an image on a DL envelope in normal resolution, it must be 220x110mm(832x416pxls), but I get a 205x100mm image and also I have already tried many times and can't print this image in normal size on Windows, but it prints normally on Ubuntu 18.04, any ideas? 
Image size is 832x416 pxls

```
PaperSize ps = new PaperSize();
ps.RawKind = (int)PaperKind.DLEnvelope;
ps.Width = 416;
ps.Height = 832;

PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;
pd.PrintPage += printDoc_PrintPage;
pd.Print();

void printDoc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = Image.FromFile(_path_img);
    e.Graphics.DrawImageUnscaled(img, 0, 0);            
}
```

Comment: You ought to get 211 x 106 with that image size.  Anyhoo, PrintDocument scales the output, default is PageUnit.Display which maps 100 pixels to an inch.  So if you want an exact size then be sure to specify it, you'll like e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, 100 * 220 / 25.4, ...)

Comment: WOW, dude, u are genius, thank you!